# python sending http response

Tags: python, http, sockets, popen

I am trying to write a *very* simple HTTP server which sends a video being streamed server side.  When a client connects, the get_video program (fictional) is started in another process and its stdout is being piped to us (under the assumption get_video sends/streams video to stdout).  I am using `subprocess.Popen()` for this.

```
import subprocess, socket

def send_video(sock, programme_id):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["get_video","--pid",programme_id], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    sock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: application/octet-stream\n\n")
    while True:
        chunk = p.stdout.read(1024)
        if chunk:
            try:
                sock.send(chunk)
            except Exception:
                pass
        else:
            break

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('',8080))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        client, address = s.accept()
        data = client.recv(1024)
        send_video(client, "123456")
        client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This barely works.  If I issue an HTTP request using `wget http://localhost:8080/blah.mp4` the whole thing does as expected - the video is streamed to the client's socket and appended to the new file, blah.mp4.

However, if I create a dummy HTML page with `<a href="http://localhost:8080/blah/mp4">download</a>` and then try 'save target/link as...' on that link, the get_video program is invoked twice.  The second time being when the video is actually sent to the client's socket.  There must be some sort of buffering going on.

Notice the `try/except` block in `send_video()`.  I was getting a 'broken pipe' error before (with the dummy HTML page method), indicating the client's socket wasn't there to be written to.  I put the `try/except` there to try and ignore it.

I am fairly confused.  The HTTP requests look the same, I'm not sure what my browser (Firefox) is doing differently to cause this.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

The header from wget:

```
GET /blah.mp4 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: 192.168.1.2:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The header from html dummy page:

```
GET /blah.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (blah) Gecko/blah Firefox/3.6.16
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The python server reported only one of each, but Wireshark reported 2 GET requests for the dummy html link method.  I don't see anything obvious here...

Comment: Print `data` after you receive it from the client. Maybe the first request is just `HEAD` or sth like this to only query your server

Comment: Why not use [`SimpleHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html)?

Comment: You can use Wireshark to find out what is different.

Comment: I'm with @pajton .  You should read and print out the incoming request so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I added a reply below to show the GET requests.

Comment: @pajton: The two requests are the same.  The second has no corresponding 200 OK with it though.

Comment: If I take out the `send_video()`, once the client has connected, and replace that with just a simple html page such as `client.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: text/html\n\n<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Hello</h1>\n</body>\n</html>\n")`.  Then if I point my browser directly to the server, the server reports two GET requests - one for the page, and one for favicon.ico.

Comment: Isn't that solution to your problem? When request for favicon.ico is made, just ignore it.

Comment: Had a closer look at Wireshark. When I hit the 'save target as' on the link,it immediately sends a GET request. A '200 OK' is sent back.  The client then sends an ACK, followed by a FIN,ACK.  The server then sends an ACK followed by (what i presume) the first packet of length 1024.  Imeediately after that, the client responds with a RST.  It then looks to be starting another GET request which hangs.  While this hangs, the server is streaming the video until it finishes before streaming it again.  At which point, the GET wakes up and accepts the video this time.  Fairly clueless I have to say.

Comment: The wget method, on the other hand, goes as follows:  GET request issued, server sends ACK followed by 200 OK response.  Client then sends ACK and server responds with packet of video.  This continues until the video is finished.

Comment: With the 'save target as' method, I get a socket.error exception with broken pipe (as I've already said) on every call to `sock.send(chunk)`.  The client must be closing its connection or something.

Answer (score 0):

It dawned on me that, because the browser sends a GET followed by a FIN,ACK after the 'save target as...' has been clicked on the link, then that'll be what is causing the broken pipe error.  It is when you choose where you want to save the file and hit 'OK' button in the browser that another GET is issued.  What was happening was I was still stuck in that `while True` loop once I had detected the broken pipe.  So I was continuing to read from the `Popen` object and failing to send it to the client every time.  Once this finished, the next GET was able to continue and the transfer was then successful.  Phew.

In short, the working code:

```
import subprocess, socket

def send_video(sock, programme_id):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["get_video","--pid",programme_id], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    sock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: application/octet-stream\n\n")
    while True:
        chunk = p.stdout.read(1024)
        if chunk:
            try:
                sock.send(chunk)
            except socket.error, e:
                sock.close()
                break
        else:
            break

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('',8080))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        client, address = s.accept()
        data = client.recv(1024)
        send_video(client, "123456")
        client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to add this as your answer, if it really is.